# how match "E-10094" using pattern matcher in java

Tags: java

How to prepare a pattern that is "any numbers immediately after 'E-' in a string using a PatternMatcher in java".

Example:

1. ACCRUE-DRINTEREST
      it contais E-
2. ACCRUE-INTEREST
      it contais E-
3. Error:E-10094##U
     it contais E-10094, numbers may be whatever after E-

I need the third String because it contains numbers after the E-

How to prepare a pattern for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or even researched how to build a regular expression?

Comment: Sorry but that looks like problem which can be solved after reading few beginning lessons from any regex tutorial. What problem is stopping you from writing your solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is on homework level and ["3. Questions asking for homework help **must** include a *summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem*, and a *description of the difficulty you are having* solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Comment: Please take your time and describe your problem properly. You list 3 examples. Examples 1 and 2 do not fit your description * "any numbers immediately after 'E-' in a string using a PatternMatcher in java"* Do example 1 and 2 need to be matched or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex

> Regex : `E-[0-9]+`

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("E-[0-9]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("E-1234");
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if(matchFound) {
            System.out.println("Match found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Match not found");
        }

}
```